# Sine wave to square wave

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have a project that involves deriving a square wave from sine wave at high frequencies, so how can I convert a sine wave to square wave at MHz frequencies? I want a circuit using an op amp that can tolerate high frequencies, 30 MHz max.

Comment: How high is "high"?

Comment: i want it 30Mhz

Comment: Look up high speed comparators. Modern devices can definitely operate at 30MHz.

Comment: Why do you think you need an op-amp?

Comment: Use a LT1016 50MHZ comparator. +/-2vdc input range. Plenty of sources. Low cost. We could draw you a schematic if a search does not find one that matches your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to meet your design criteria is with a high-speed mid-reference comparator... like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feXjtm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The precise value of the resistors is not important so long as they are matched. Lower values will be more stable vs. temperature and manufacturing variation, while higher values will be more energy efficient.

I've made a number of assumptions here that you will need to ensure are valid in your application:

1. You have sufficient gain-bandwidth-product (GBP) in the Op-amp you select. If you don't need any gain (x1) then you need at least 30MHz GBP.
2. **The voltage of your sine-wave signal is also mid-reference (it's "zero" is halfway between your V+ and V- used with the Op-Amp.**
3. Your input signal's dynamic range fits within the input range of the Op-Amp.

Comment: There are a few things wrong with the above but you are on the right track.  1) What happens to U1 when the input sine wave goes below ground?  2) Duty cycle is proportional to the amplitude of the input sine wave compared to the value of the reference voltage formed by resistors R1 & R2.

Comment: This only works if the sinewave source has a bias on it equal to half the supply voltage.

Comment: @dwayne Of course. This was/is clearly noted in the answer. That's restricted by point #3.

Comment: @david Of course. This was/is clearly noted in the answer. I've bolded it for you.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been simpler and a more direct answer to the question to simply show the comparator with bipolar supplies in the first place? And we are talking about a high-speed comparator here, not an opamp, right?

Comment: @Dave -- Yes. You're right. I'll revise.

Comment: it doesnot work with my opamp ca3130 . 15Mhz ... its the highest opamp freq in my country ...why it doesnt work ??

Comment: @omar -- What are your gain and edge-rate requirements?

Comment: i want any bandwidth can get high freq until mega hz